# I cannot get the async/await function to run as expected

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm writing for the first time some code in nodejs (and javascript) and I cannot get an understanding of how the async/await works, even after testing code from this forum on the topic. I simply cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

I run node version 10 and I have as said already tried various examples, also without being able to do what I want.

```
function myFunctionWithCallBack(time){
    console.log("Started: " + time);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Callback: " + time);
        return ("Return: " + time);
    }, time)
}

async function executeAsyncTask() {
    let value = await myFunctionWithCallBack(2000);
    console.log(value);
    value = await myFunctionWithCallBack(5000);
    console.log(value);
}

executeAsyncTask();

/*
**Actual result:**
Started: 2000
undefined
Started: 5000
undefined
Callback: 2000
Callback: 5000

**Desired result:**
Started: 2000
Callback: 2000
Return: 2000
Started: 5000
Callback: 5000
*/
```

Comment: async/await work with **Promises**, they are not callbacks - which is an other type of asynchronous functions.

Comment: What part should be a promise then? The "myFunctionWithCallBack"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, async/await works with Promises, and not callbacks, which are a different type of asynchronous functions.

Your code would look like this with Promises:

```
function myFunctionWithCallBack(time){
    console.log("Started: " + time);
    return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Callback: " + time);
        resolve("Return: " + time);
    }, time)
  )
}

async function executeAsyncTask() {
    let value = await myFunctionWithCallBack(2000);
    console.log(value);
    value = await myFunctionWithCallBack(5000);
    console.log(value);
}

executeAsyncTask();
```

Comment: Ahhh, got it! Thanks for the info!

Comment: Sure, don't hesitate to upvote/accept answer if it helped you ! :)

Comment: Done! Sorry for delay. Somewhat also new to being an active member on the community.

Comment: @MattsNorrbohm Welcome to the community ! You said done but I don't see any upvote/accept on the answer, there is an 'accept' button next to my post